# Magento 2 Folder Structure Differ

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento 2...and trying to learn CODEPOOL in Magento 2. This is a very basic question regarding Magento 2 Folder Structure.Magento 2 is differ from other previous version like Magento 1.9.1,1.9.0 ...

Comment: Magento 2 has not code pool, now the structure in project is `app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want more detailed solution

Comment: @Balachandran, Than, please provide more detailed question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento 2 is significantly different from Magento 1.X and s not backward compatible as well.

**In Magento 2,**

- All Custom Modules will go in **app/code**
- Module Name will be something similar to `app/code/[Company]/[Module]`
- View of the module (layout XMLs, Template .phtmls, Module Javascripts, LESS, CSS and all related files) will now go inside the Module Folder itself, making the module is standalone and independant
- No More codepools. Core team has written their own modules for functionalities and core code lives in `[MAGE_ROOT]/vendor/magento/`. for example Catalog Module is now at `[MAGE_ROOT]/vendor/magento/module-catalog` having the module name `Magento_Catalog`
- Even the Magento themes are now coming as Modules, look for `[MAGE_ROOT]/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma` or `[MAGE_ROOT]/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend`
- Usage of Advanced Design Patterns and Features like Namespaces, Automatic Dependancy Injection, Static Content Generation

**Some Used Technologies**

- LESS, jQuery, RequireJS, knockout.js and More
- Varnish, Redis, Memcached
- Solr
- A complete list as per the documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/tech-stack.html

**Good Tutorials to Follow**

- http://alanstorm.com/
- https://www.ashsmith.io/

Give it a try. It's complex, more advanced. But worth learning...

Answer (score 2):

```
Magento 2 all module reside inside app/code folder.
Inside app/code folder
/etc (main configuration folder module.xml)
/Setup (database table related file)
/Controller(action file)
/Model(Business logic)
/Helper (Miscellaneous data)
/Block (Block Template function file)
/view (phtml and layout file with css and js file)
/i18n (For translation language feature)

There are no core/community/local folder and those all folders are remove.
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento use complete MVC pattern as following:-
1.complete module code resides in single folder:VendorName/ModuleName
2.No core/community/local folder
3.complete front end data (view data) resides into view folder.
4.Module register trough registration.php file.
5.dependency manage by composer.js file.

Comment: Magento 2 doesn't use MVC, it is MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 code structure is different from Magento 1. Code can be found under **[MagentoRoot]/app/code** and can also be installed under **[MagentoRoot]/vendor directory** using composer. Frontend Themes can be created under **[MagentoRoot]/app/design/frontend** and Admin Themes can be created under **[MagentoRoot]/app/design/adminhtml**

Answer (score 0):

As far as concerned with Magento 2, the code pool structure of Magento 2 is different than Magento 1.

There are directories of modules where code found in Magento 2 as:

1. app/code
2. vendor
3. design/frontend
4. design/adminhtml

Every module follows the directory structure as VendorName/ModuleName inside the directory app/code, all the Code can be found under [MagentoRoot]/app/code, and can similar third-party modules also can be installed under /vendor directory using composer.json.

Please check the complete documentation:
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/build/component-file-structure/
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-module-in-magento-2/

Answer (score -1):

magento extension folder structure :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In Magneto 2 very easy to understand folder structure
Common directories

Following are some common module directories:

Block: contains PHP view classes as part of Model View Controller(MVC) vertical implementation of module logic.

Controller: contains PHP controller classes as part of MVC vertical implementation of module logic.

etc: contains configuration files; in particular, module.xml, which is required.

Model: contains PHP model classes as part of MVC vertical implementation of module logic.

Setup: contains classes for module database structure and data setup which are invoked when installing or upgrading.

Additional directories

Additional folders can be added for configuration and other ancillary functions for items like plugin-ins, localization, and layout files.

Api: contains any PHP classes exposed to the API.

i18n: contains localization files.

Plugin: contains any needed plug-ins.

view: contains view files, including static view files, design templates, email templates, and layout files

Theme file structure

A typical theme file structure can look like the following:

├── composer.json ├── etc │   └── view.xml ├── i18n │   └── en_US.csv ├── LICENSE_AFL.txt ├── LICENSE.txt ├── media │   └── preview.jpg ├── registration.php └── web ├── css │   ├── email.less │   ├── print.less │   ├── source │   │   ├── _actions-toolbar.less │   │   ├── _breadcrumbs.less │   │   ├── _buttons.less │   │   ├── components │   │   │   └── _modals_extend.less │   │   ├── _icons.less │   │   ├── _layout.less │   │   ├── _theme.less │   │   ├── _tooltips.less │   │   ├── _typography.less │   │   └── _variables.less │   ├── _styles.less │   ├── styles-l.less │   └── styles-m.less ├── images │   └── logo.svg └── js ├── navigation-menu.js ├── responsive.js └── theme.js

Common directories

Typical theme directories are:

etc: Contains configuration files such as the view.xml file which contains image configurations for all images and thumbnails.

i18n: Translation dictionaries, if any.

media: Theme preview images (screen capture of your theme) can be put in here.

web: Optional directory that contains static files organized into the following subdirectories:

css/source: Contains a theme’s less configuration files that invoke mixins for global elements from the Magento UI library, and the theme.less file that overrides the default variables values.

css/source/lib: Contains view files that override the UI library files stored in lib/web/css/source/lib.

fonts: The folder to place the different fonts for your theme.

images: Static images folder.

js: The folder for your JavaScript files.